# Using delimiters to split Query table data into rows

Tags: vba

I need query table data in excel to use comma as a delimiter for columns and curly bracket '{' as a delimiter for rows.

I know i can use the ".TextFileOtherDelimiter" property to use the curly bracket as a delimiter. But how do i get the data to go into the next row?

**CODE**

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & url & "", Destination:=Worksheets("temp").Range("$A$1"))
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
.Refresh
End With
```

Above code works fine for splitting data by commas into different columns.

Answer (score 1):

Do this first

```
Dim X As Variant
X = Split(Range("A1").Value, "{") 'or X = Split(YourVariable, "{")
Worksheets("temp").Range("$A$1").Resize(UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(X)
```

then run your text to columns code

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & url & "", 
Destination:=Worksheets("temp").Range("$A$1"))
.TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
.TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
.Refresh
End With
```